# Resource mapping in a Ruby on Rails URL (RESTful API)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I'm having a bit of difficulty coming up with the right answer to this, so I will solicit my problem here. I'm working on a RESTFul API. Naturally, I have multiple resources, some of which consist of parent to child relationships, some of which are stand alone resources. Where I'm having a bit of difficulty is figuring out how to make things easier for the folks who will be building clients against my API.

The situation is this. Hypothetically I have a 'Street' resource. Each street has multiple homes. So Street :has_many to Homes and Homes :belongs_to Street. If a user wants to request an HTTP GET on a specific home resource, the following should work:

`http://mymap/streets/5/homes/10`

That allows a user to get information for a home with the id 10. Straight forward. My question is, am I breaking the rules of the book by giving the user access to:

`http://mymap/homes/10`

Technically that home resource exists on its own without the street. It makes *sense* that it exists as its own entity without an encapsulating street, even though business logic says otherwise.

What's the best way to handle this?

> EDIT! In spirit of becoming a good StackOverflow citizen, I've come back with a supported code block for how to implement they above.

```
map.resources :streets,
              :has_many => :homes
              :shallow => true
```

This will create both types of routes that I was looking for.

Comment: That shallow option is interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your Home records can only belong to one Street, then the relationship won't be confused when you're examining a Home individually. You'll still be able to back-track to the associated Street record for whatever reason.

It's in situations where you have a many-to-many relationship that de-nesting your REST structure can get you into trouble. If a particular record only makes sense in a particular context, and you remove that context, obviously there is confusion.

I think in your particular case you may not need to implement both approaches, but instead go with the "flatter" approach that reduces the complexity of the URL.

Comment: If you _do_ offer both options, you'll want to be sure to use `rel="canonical"` on one of them to link to the other. (Probably link _from_ the deeper _to_ the shallower version.)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that is how shallow routes work and are used a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I really like [this](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources) approach. I recomend to read it. In short this article says that you shouldn't nest your resources more then 1 level. And if it is possible that nested resource can be shallowed, then do it.

In one of my applications I really messed things up with nested resources. I go even to 3 or 4 deep and it become a nightmare...

Nesting is really nice if it makes things simpler. If not, give it up!